# OpenCV Assertion Failed with Stitcher

Tags: c++, image, opencv, panoramas, image-stitching

I'm writing a program that takes a video as input and return a panorama image. I'm executing this code:

```
vector< Mat > vImg;
Mat rImg;
Mat img;



VideoCapture cap("../Debug/vid/vid.avi");

if (!cap.isOpened())
{
    cout << "Can't open video";
    waitKey(0);
    return ;
}


//default stitcher
Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(true);

//set orb finder
Ptr<FeaturesFinder> finder=new OrbFeaturesFinder();
stitcher.setFeaturesFinder(finder); 

//set seam resolution
stitcher.setSeamEstimationResol(0.08);

//set confidence threshold
stitcher.setPanoConfidenceThresh(0.5);

//set warper
Ptr<WarperCreator> warper = new cv::PlaneWarper();
stitcher.setWarper(warper);

//set exposure compensation
Ptr<ExposureCompensator> exposure_compensator = ExposureCompensator::createDefault(ExposureCompensator::GAIN);
stitcher.setExposureCompensator(exposure_compensator);


//set seam finder
Ptr<SeamFinder> seam_finder = new DpSeamFinder(DpSeamFinder::COLOR_GRAD);
stitcher.setSeamFinder(seam_finder);

//set matcher
Ptr<FeaturesMatcher> matcher = new BestOf2NearestMatcher(true);
stitcher.setFeaturesMatcher(matcher);


//sett wave correction
stitcher.setWaveCorrection(true);

cap >> img;
vImg.push_back(img);
vImg.push_back(img);    



int counter = 1;



while (counter < total_frames)
{

    Mat img_loop;

    cap >> img_loop;


    vImg.at(1) = img_loop;



    stitcher.stitch(vImg, rImg);


    if (rImg.rows>0 && rImg.cols>0)
    {
        imshow("debug", rImg);      


        vImg.at(0) = rImg;
    }



    rImg = NULL;


    counter ++;

}
```

but it gives to me the "Assertion Failed (dims <=2 && data ...)" error.
What the problem could be?

I'm using visual studio 2013 community, opencv 2.4.10 and windows 7 x64

**EDIT**
Added the "call stack"

```
    KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16() 
Unknown>        msvcr120d.dll!_CxxThrowException(void *pExceptionObject, const_s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo) Riga 154  C++
    opencv_core2410d.dll!774ec7f8() Sconosciuto
```

**EDIT**
I notice that if I stitch 2 identical images it gives me error. It is normal?

Comment: Have you tried showing the images before stitching?

Comment: Yes,with imshow the images are correctly showed!

Comment: I tried with the debugger. If I not put a waitkey after the imshow it opens only a grey window!

Comment: yes, that is expected... if you want to show it for a brief moment, use a small number like `waitkey(10)`, but that should not give you an assertion error

Comment: Do you think I should try the version 3 of opencv?

Comment: I haven't tested well, but you may give it a try. Where did you initialized the stitcher variable? I think you are missing a step, but I am not sure, can you edit and add all the places where you use the stitcher variable? I think I have an idea what is wrong

Comment: Edited with the initialization part!

Comment: Thanks, have you tried to use false in the try_use_gpu value? (the one when creating the stitcher). I read that the default values are for cpu mode... Also, have you tried to use the default stitcher without any of the extra things (warper, resol, etc)?

Comment: yes, with the default values it gives the "Insufficient memory" error. I can't really figure the problem :/

Comment: I noticed with the debugger that rImg after the stitch.stich command is always empty. Could this be helpfull for you?

Comment: Hmmmm, this insufficient memory error is also weird.... does this happen with the first pair? well, there is your error jeje... the image is empty, so when you go to the second iteration, one image has something and the other one is empty... so it is a mismatch in the size and consequently gives you the assert error.... you should check the return value of the function stitch (it returns `Stitcher::Status` that can be casted as an int)

Comment: I've tried with Stitcher::status and it gives me 1 (I think it's ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS), so I read 4 frame at time in this way: `cap >> img_loop;
  cap >> img_loop2;
  cap >> img_loop3;
                vImg.at(1) = img_loop;
  vImg.at(2) = img_loop2;
  vImg.at(3) = img_loop3;` and it gives to me the insufficient memory error.

Comment: Do you think that doing the pipeline by hand instead using the default stitcher could resolve the problem?

Comment: it seems that it needs more than 2 images... now you have another error.... Insufficient memory error... it is weird.... usually this error appears when it is in GPU.... if it is in CPU usually it doesn't tell you... either your computer stops responding or the the program dies unexpectedly. try using `Stitcher::createDefault(false);`

Comment: I tried with `Stitcher::createDefault(false);` but it gives me the insufficient memory error.. Could be that images are too similar?

Comment: can you debug it, and see where it gives that error?

Comment: You means debug the stitch function?

Comment: your program, see which instruction (of the opencv stitch) gives you the memory insufficient... To have an idea of what may be happening...

Comment: I don't know why but I can't debug the stitch function (I've set Microsoft server symbol). However, this is the error that the code above launches:
`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)si
ze.p[0] && (unsigned)i1 < (unsigned)size.p[1] && type() == DataType<_Tp>::type)
in cv::Mat_<int>::operator (), file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\op
encv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp, line 993`

Comment: But that is your first error... that it was fixed (one of the images being empty)

Comment: You're right (sorry this problem makes me mad xD). Here's the error:
`OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 501945556 bytes) in cv::Ou
tOfMemoryError, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\co
re\src\alloc.cpp, line 52`

Comment: Well, it is trying to allocate around 500 MB, quite a lot for stitching 4 images.... Do you have the backtrace (add it to your question) to see which function is responsible...

Comment: Really I've remodified the code, so it's stitching just 2 images. For the call stack, I have onoly this `  KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16() Sconosciuto
> msvcr120d.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo) Riga 154 C++
  opencv_core2410d.dll!774ec7f8() Sconosciuto
` but I think it's not usefull :/. Ps: Ireally appreciate your dedication to my problem :D

Comment: Sorry I've edited the post with the stack call!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved implementing manualing the stitching pipeline. Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is about memory allocation, You can try to declare your vector as a static.

```
static vector<Mat> vImg;
```

I am not sure about that but i faced this problem while allocating huge array and this trick solved my problem instead of using pointers.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'll give a try later and I will let you know!